# C program how to print in table format alignment

Tags: c

The input is retrieve from text file. Which contain information of

- product ID
- product Name
- Product Quantity
- product Price

  ```
  1    RAYBAN  1   450.000000 
  900 KEYBOARD 100 290.000000
  78 MINERALWATER 123 345.000000
  2 RAYBAN 2 450.000000
  ```

After printing the output through command prompt. It was not align with the 1st item. How to make it align with the title of table. As you can see the input of line 1 and 4 almost the same.

Here is the output.

[image]

Here is the full code. With `gotoxy` function. The display function is on

```
int displayProduct()
```

There is a line of code for table titles and also the printf from TXT File.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void gotoxy(int column, int line);
int main();
int addProduct();
int displayProduct(); //prototype

struct product {
    int quantity, reorder, i, id;
    char name[20];
    float price;
};

COORD coord = { 0, 0 };

void gotoxy(int x, int y) {
    coord.X = x; coord.Y = y;

    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
}

int main() {
    int choice;

    gotoxy(17, 5);
    printf("\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2 SYZ INVENTORY PROGRAM \xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2");

    gotoxy(17, 20);
        printf("\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2");

    gotoxy(22, 8);
    printf("1. Add Product\n\n");

    gotoxy(22, 10);
    printf("2. Display Product\n\n");

    gotoxy(22, 12);
    printf("3. Search Product\n\n");

    gotoxy(22, 14);
    printf("4. Reorder Level of Product\n\n");

    gotoxy(22, 16);
    printf("5. Update Product\n\n");

    gotoxy(22, 18);
    printf("6. Exit\n\n");

    gotoxy(22, 22);
    printf("Please Enter Your Choice : ");
    scanf(" %d", &choice);

    switch (choice) {
      case 1:
        addProduct();
        break;
      case 2:
        displayProduct();
        break;
      case 3:
        searchProduct();
        break;
      case 4:
        reorderProduct();
        break;
      case 5:
        updateProduct();
        break;
      case 6:
        break;
      default:
        system("cls");
        main();
    }
    return (0);
}

/*MENU CODE ENDS !*/

int addProduct() {
    FILE *fp;

    int i = 0;
    struct product a;
    system("cls");

    fp = fopen("inventory.txt", "a+t");

    char checker;

    do {
        system("cls");

        gotoxy(17, 5);
        printf("\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2 SYZ INVENTORY PROGRAM \xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2");

        gotoxy(17, 20);
        printf("\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2");

        gotoxy(22, 8);
        printf("Enter product ID : ");
        scanf(" %d", &a.id);

        gotoxy(22, 10);
        printf("Enter product name : ");
        scanf(" %s", a.name);

        gotoxy(22, 12);
        printf("Enter product quantity : ");
        scanf(" %d", &a.quantity);

        gotoxy(22, 14);
        printf("Enter product price : ");
        scanf(" %f", &a.price);

        gotoxy(22, 17);
        fprintf(fp, "%d %s %d %f\n\n", a.id, a.name, a.quantity, a.price); //SAVE TO TXT FILE LINE !
        printf("Record saved!\n\n");

        fclose(fp);

        gotoxy(22, 22);
        printf("Do you want to enter new product? Y / N : ");

        scanf(" %c", &checker);
        checker = toupper(checker);

        i++;

        system("cls");
    } while (checker=='Y');

    if (checker == 'N') {
        main();
    } else {
        do {
            system("cls");

            gotoxy(17, 5);
            printf("\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2 SYZ INVENTORY PROGRAM \xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2");

            gotoxy(17, 20);
            printf("\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2");

            gotoxy(18, 8);
            printf(">>> Wrong Input! Please Enter Y Or N Only! <<<");

            gotoxy(19, 12);
            printf("Do You Want To Enter New Product? Y / N : ");
            scanf(" %c", &checker);
            checker = toupper(checker);
        } while (checker != 'Y' && checker != 'N');

        if (checker == 'Y'){
            addProduct();
        }

        if (checker == 'N') {
            system("cls");
            main();
        }
    }
    return(0);
}

/*ADD PRODUCT LINE ENDS !*/

int displayProduct() {
    FILE *fp;
    struct product a;

    char true;
    system("cls");

    fp = fopen("inventory.txt", "r");

    gotoxy(17, 5);
    printf("\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2 SYZ INVENTORY PROGRAM \xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2");

    gotoxy(5, 6);
    printf("======================================================================");

    gotoxy(5, 7);
    printf("Product ID\t\t Product Name\t\t Quantity\t Unit Price\n"); //TABLE TITLES !

    gotoxy(5, 8);
    printf("======================================================================");

    gotoxy(5,10);
    while (fscanf(fp, "%d %s %d %f", &a.id, a.name, &a.quantity, &a.price) == 4) {
        printf("%d\t\t\t %s\t\t\t %d\t\t %.2f\n\n", a.id, a.name, a.quantity, a.price); //PRINT FROM TXT FILE TO COMMAND PROMPT.
    }
    fclose(fp);

    printf("\t\t \xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2");

    printf("\nPress any key to return to Main Menu.");

    getch();

    int main();

    return (0);
}
```

Updated one, changes made :

```
gotoxy(5,10);
                while(fscanf(fp, "%d %s %d %f", &a.id, a.name, &a.quantity, &a.price)==4)
                {
                printf("%-10d\t\t %-12s\t\t %8d\t %8.2f\n\n", a.id, a.name, a.quantity, a.price);
                }

                fclose(fp);
```

[image]

Comment: Use a screen-library like ncurses if you need formatted masks in your console. That `gotoxy`-only formatting is pretty outdated and error-prone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code to print the inventory should use the length specifier in `printf` format like this:

```
gotoxy(0, 10);
while (fscanf(fp, "%d %s %d %f", &a.id, a.name, &a.quantity, &a.price) == 4) {
    printf("    %-10d\t\t %-12s\t\t %8d\t %8.2f\n\n", a.id, a.name, a.quantity, a.price);
}
```

Some notes regarding the code:

- it is very bad style to call `main()` recursively.  Use a loop instead.
- write a function that prints the header instead of duplicating the code multiple times.
- the statement `int main();` at the end of `displayProduct()` is a local declaration for function `main`, it does not generate a call.

Comment: Thank you. I'm still learning. Will improvise myself :)
Can you check on the updated command prompt. It seems, the 1st line only follow.

Comment: The problem comes from the `gotoxy(5, 10);`  before the loop. Only the first line has an indentation of `5`.  I updated the answer to fix this issue.

Comment: Okay cool. Manage to solve it. I got 1 more question, what does it means by -10, -12,8 ?

Comment: @AlifKhair: the number after the `%` is the minimum field width for the conversion. If preceded by a `-` the conversion is left aligned and padded with spaces, otherwise it is right aligned, preceded by spaces. eg: `%-10d` converts the number `42` into the characters `42          `. Using this feature, you can format the text output for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

your menu doesn't go back to the main menu after pressing any key,
there you have to use main(); instead ogf int main();