# trying to format my printf to line up the dollar signs and cents - c source

Tags: c, printf

want to make outcome look kinda like this :

```
# of people Served:       8
Bill Amount:       $ 399.60
Surcharge Amount:   $ 80.00
Final Bill Amount: $ 479.60
```

doesnt show well here i mean lined up at the zeroes

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

 int main()
{
    int numberPeople;
    float surchargeAmount, totalBill, finalBill;

    printf("please enter number of people: ");
    scanf(" %d", &numberPeople);
    if (numberPeople <= 5.0)
    {
        surchargeAmount = 0;
    }
    else if (numberPeople <= 10.0)
    {
        surchargeAmount = 80.0;
    }
    else if (numberPeople <= 20.0)
    {
        surchargeAmount = 150.0;
    }
    else if (numberPeople > 20.0)
    {
        surchargeAmount = 200.0;
    }
    totalBill = numberPeople * 49.95;
    finalBill = (numberPeople * 49.95) + surchargeAmount;
    printf("# of people served:%d \n"
        "Bill Amount:%.2f \n"
        "Surcharge Amount:%.2f \n"
        "Final Bill Amount:%.2f \n", numberPeople, totalBill, 
surchargeAmount, finalBill);
    getch();
    return 0;
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39025074/c-program-how-to-print-in-table-format-alignment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548909/smart-way-to-format-tables-on-stdout-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to align your output message using appropriate `field width` in your [printf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) format specifiers.

For example:

```
printf( "# of people served: %d \n"
        "Bill Amount:        %8.2f \n"
        "Surcharge Amount:   %8.2f \n"
        "Final Bill Amount:  %8.2f \n",
        numberPeople, totalBill, 
        surchargeAmount, finalBill);
```

Output:

```
# of people served: 3 
Bill Amount:          149.85 
Surcharge Amount:       0.00 
Final Bill Amount:    149.85
```

Here's a live example: https://ideone.com/Iko1BY

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define CURRENCY "$"

struct Bill {
    char* item;
    double amount;
};

enum {
    BUF_SIZE = 16
};

int main(void)
{
    char buf[BUF_SIZE];
    struct Bill bill[] = {
        {"First:", 123.45},
        {"Second:", 0.50},
        {"Third:", 123456.78}
    };

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(bill) / sizeof(struct Bill); i++) {
        snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), CURRENCY " %.2f", bill[i].amount);
        printf("%-10s %16s\n", bill[i].item, buf);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

So you can get:

```
First:             $ 123.45
Second:              $ 0.50
Third:          $ 123456.78
```